# amdgpu install fail in cubic

Tags: dependencies, amdgpu

Copy amdgpu-19.20 folder to cubic and perform ./amdgpu-install then below error message display on the cubic?

Same method is install successful in the live system. May I use another way if I install amdgpu in the cubic environment?

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 amdgpu-hwe : Depends: amdgpu-lib-hwe (= 19.20-812932) but it is not going to be installed
 amdgpu-lib32 : Depends: amdgpu-lib (= 19.20-812932) but it is not going to be installed or
                         amdgpu-lib-hwe (= 19.20-812932) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libdrm2-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:2.4.97-812932)
                Depends: libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:i386 (= 1:2.4.97-812932)
                Depends: libllvm7.1-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:7.1-812932)
                Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-client0:i386 (= 1.15.0-812932)
                Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-server0:i386 (= 1.15.0-812932)
                Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-egl1:i386 (= 1.15.0-812932)
                Depends: libxatracker2-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:18.3.0-812932)
                Depends: libgbm1-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:18.3.0-812932)
                Depends: libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (= 1:18.3.0-812932)
                Depends: libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386 (= 1:18.3.0-812932)
                Depends: libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (= 1:18.3.0-812932)
                Depends: libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (= 1:18.3.0-812932)
                Depends: libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (= 1:18.3.0-812932)
                Depends: libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:i386 (= 1:18.3.0-812932)
                Depends: libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386 (= 1:18.3.0-812932)
                Depends: libosmesa6-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:18.3.0-812932)
                Depends: mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386 (= 1:18.3.0-812932)
                Depends: mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386 (= 1:18.3.0-812932)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Looks like it is looking for packages for 32 bit architecture (i386). In prior versions of ubuntu, `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` used to install the x32 bit dependencies; not sure if it works in more recent versions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)